# Why can't I ping my cloud server IP running Nginx from my windows box?

Tags: debian, nginx

I have a cloud server running Debian Wheezy. 
Webserver is nginx.

If I go to www.mydomain.com in internet explorer I get my webserver just fine. However If I go to a command prompt on a remote machine and ping www.mydomain.com or domain.com I get request timed out.

This happens if I type the name of the domain or the ip.

Why is this? How can I enable ping requests on my linux box?

When i type

```
sudo iptables -L
```

The following is returned: -

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

If I try to tracert to the domain the tracert goes through 8 hops, until it reaches my server IP then the server IP is displayed in tracrt and every other entry after that, reads "Request timed out".

Is there something I need to set in the Debian firewall to enable ping requests if so how do I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Could be your own instance, or firewalling on a hosting level. Check your instance by running "sudo iptables -L"

Comment: Thanks tink. When i run that command there appears to be nothing set, i see this:-

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

have edited original question to include this information now

Comment: Right - so it's NOT your machine.  Have you tried other ICMP types, e.g. run a traceroute against your IP from outside? What does that say?

Comment: i just tried tracert, and the hops work until it gets to my server IP, then i just get a series of 'request timed out' again. // I should add in case it is relevent, the reason i found this out in the first place is I was trying to connect into tightvnc, which I setup today, but tightvnc says it can't connect to the server also. Yet when i go to the address in internet exlporer I get my webserver, and I can connect fine into the box through SSH.

Comment: Hmmm ... sounds funky. I'd say it's something your hoster (cloud provider) is doing.  Contact their support?

Comment: It could be many things but you should make sure it's not a rule in the `NAT` table:  `iptables -nvL -t nat`.  You should also try to ping it from the host to see if it replies.  If it does, ping requests are blocked upstream at your provider's firewall.  Not sure why you'd worry though since the server is obviously reachable.  If they block it, there's nothing you'll be able to do to get it unblocked (they'd have their reasons).